# Google Drive API files:COPY returns 404 error

Tags: php, curl, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

When I run 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files' successfully works

However if I try 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}/copy' it returns a 404 Error

- Have double checked the 'fileId'.
- Have cleared the cache and tried but not working
- Have checked the Scope Permissions...
- The scopes are 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly'](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly%27)

The same example, If I Try on 'Drive Explorer Try Now', it works fine there as well. So what's wrong not able to figure out

```
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1ZYyl0MzfWy_V5Io3N0BTsF19pNiX7s23BqYPbQKplvU/copy';   

$ch = curl_init();      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '. $access_token));
$data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);     

if($http_code != 200) 
    throw new Exception('Error : Failed');
    
return $data;
```

Comment: You have only included the code for the GET can i see the code for your copy method?

Answer (score 0):

[404 not found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) means just that that the end point you are trying is not found.

But your copy does not work and you say you have checked that its the same file i did.

I wonder Copy is a http Post request did you forget to send it as a post?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem....Dont know sometimes, forgot simple simple stuff...couldn't notice it....thanks so, I've added curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); this line and COPY works fine! cheers

Comment: glad it helped please remember to accept the answer if it helped.  your reputation will also increase